# Firebase Storage Context with Storage Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage, react-context

I am using Firebase and React and learning how to use React Contexts. I created a context that queries Firebase to get data from there (user's files URL's for example). The context works fine, however, I can't get the context to become asynchronous. I haven't seen any examples of this and am not sure if it's possible. My code is below.

StorageContext.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from './FirebaseConfiguration';
import fire from './FirebaseConfig';
import { useAuth } from './AuthContext';

const StorageContext = React.createContext();

export function useStorage() {
  return useContext(StorageContext);
}

export function StorageProvider({ children }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const [fileURLs, setFilesURL] = useState([]);

  async function getUserData() {
    var storage = fire.storage();
    var storageRef = storage.ref(currentUser.uid);

    storageRef
      .listAll()
      .then(function (result) {
        result.items.forEach(function (imageRef, i) {
          let temp = filesUploaded;
          temp.push(imageRef.name);
          setFilesUploaded(temp);
        });
        console.log(filesUploaded);
        // console.log(getData(filesUploaded));
        getData(filesUploaded);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  const value = { getUserData };
  return (
    <StorageContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</StorageContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStorage } from './Contexts/StorageContext';

export default function Dashboard() {
  const { getUserData } = useStorage();

  async function getData() {
    await getUserData().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      console.log('data');
    </div>
```

The useEffect in Dashbaord.js runs fine, the problem is that getUserData() returns immediately even though it should be waiting until (and thus the `.then((data) => { console.log(data) }` is empty.

Is it possible to run a Context Asynchronously? Or is there another problem that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it returns immediately is that you use `then` and not `await`. Rewrite your function to this and it should work:

```js
async function getUserData() {
  var storage = fire.storage();
  var storageRef = storage.ref(currentUser.uid);

  const result = await storageRef.listAll();

  result.items.forEach(function (imageRef, i) {
    let temp = filesUploaded;
    temp.push(imageRef.name);
    setFilesUploaded(temp);
  });
  console.log(filesUploaded);
  // console.log(getData(filesUploaded));
  getData(filesUploaded);
}
```